# How to set View in Fragment without create class extends Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I don't want to create new class extends Fragment, I want to create new object of Fragment:

```
Fragment myFrag = new Fragment();
```

But how to set main view (layout) in my myFrag?

When I extends Fragment via creating new class I do:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
}
```

But in my case how to do it?

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create new class extends Fragment.

You can use anonymous class, but this is anti-pattern.

```
    Fragment myFrag = new Fragment() {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
        }
    };
```

AndroidStudio shows a warning.

> Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by
>   the system, and anonymous class are not static

This answer may be useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/5183999